# In Chrome/Firefox Developer Tools, is it Possible to Hide All But the First Two Errors? (Since React Gives LOTS of Garbage Errors)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

In React when things go wrong you often wind up with A LOT of error messages in your console.  Some can be duplicates of the original error, and some are unrelated errors *caused by* the original error creating invalid conditions.

In a normal JS app this happens, just less often, because the first error generally halts code execution. But in React, its rendering strategy often results in new errors after existing ones (and often they're quite verbose).

Thus, you often have a wall of text to scroll back up through on every refresh, when you actually need just: **A)** the original error, and/or **B)** the message React throws right after (ie. where that error *actually* occurred).

My question is:

**Is it possible to configure any browser's dev tools to collapse or hide error messages after the first two (since reloading)?**

Can I use a configuration option, or an extension, or a global error handler that calls a console function I don't know of, or *something* ... to automatically make it so I only see the first two on reload?

Comment: To whoever downvoted: what was wrong about this question?  It's 100% code/development related, it's not asking for a recommendation (it's asking for a specific answer to a specific question), there's no missing code examples ...

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess it's because it doesn't seem like a wise decision, anyhow, have you considered an ErrorBoundary?

Comment: I have one error boundary for the whole app, but I'm unclear on how I could use them to solve this problem, especially since many errors happens outside of components (eg. in `fetch`).  Also, could you elaborate on the decision not being wise?  What's the downside of collapsing "noise" (errors after the first two) to make it more convenient to see the "signal" (top two)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only showing first n errors/warning is not possible from the developer tools** at least for Chrome 86.0.4240.75 or earlier.

If you want to create your own plugin, you can for sure achieve this!, but there are multiple things you can try to keep unnecessary logs filtered from the console.

For example, you can decide what level og messages you want to see:
[image]

or filter messages by text or regex from filter box
[image]

or filter messages from a particular file:
[image]

Learn more about log filtering from [official guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/log#filter).

Comment: If you could edit answer to clearly say "this is currently impossible" (you don't have to use those words, but something to that effect), I'd appreciate it.